# Reading a well-formatted text file

Tags: c, malloc, scanf, realloc

Given the well-formatted text file called input.txt below:

```
Yesterday snowed
Today is hot
Tomorrow will rain
Next week will earthquake
```

How can I read the text file line by line and also dynamically allocate memory to each English word as a character array if I do not know the length of each English word since I do  not want to waste 1000 bytes on a short word. Should realloc be used in this case? The following is my code:

```
    int main() {
         FILE* pfile = fopen("input.txt", "r");
         int i = 0;
         while (i != 0) {
              char* stringLiteral = (char*) malloc(1000 * sizeof(char));
              i = fscanf(pfile, "%s", stringLiteral);
              insertString(stringLiteral);
         }
         fclose("input.txt");
         return 1;
    }
    
    void insertString(char* charArray) {
         /*This function inserts a char array to a linked list*/
    }
```

Comment: you cant dynamically allocate mrmory **"as a string literal"***

Comment: Did you try a simple algorithm: 1. Read one character. 2. Is that character a newline? 3. If not, allocate more space and put it in your buffer. 4. If it is a newline, then end reading a line.

Comment: @KamilCuk one realloc is 100% more effective than plenty :)

Comment: @P__J__ Sorry, my bad. It should be a char array

Comment: An effective approach would be to use an input buffer with a fixed size; `char buffer[1024];` (choose a _reasonable_ size, depending on the kind of data you're reading in). You can then allocate the necessary memory dynamically without reallocations.

Comment: It's 1000 bytes. Unless you're doing this a million times, or are running this code on a system with *kilobytes* of memory, who cares? You could `realloc` to trim but unless you're doing other allocations that is unlikely to have a distinct impact on your memory footprint.

Comment: `fclose("input.txt");` is wrong usage. It should be `fclose(pfile);`

Comment: If you're willing to consider extensions to standard C, you could see if the `%ms` conversion specifier for `fscanf` is available on your platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want you can use `realloc`, yes, in that case you would need to reallocate, smaller pieces of memory.

You can even reallocate `char` by `char` stretching the string as it's being populated and not waste a single byte.

Example with comments:

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Ar4c7waEstubSrbB)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    FILE *pfile = fopen("input.txt", "r");

    if (pfile == NULL) { //check for errors in opening file
        perror("fopen");
    }
    else {
        int c;
        int i = 0; //string iterator
        char *stringLiteral;
        stringLiteral = malloc(1); //initial allocation
        if(stringLiteral == NULL) {
            perror("malloc");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        while ((c = fgetc(pfile)) != EOF) { //until the end of the file is reached
            if (c != '\n') { //until the line ends
                stringLiteral = realloc(stringLiteral, i + 1); //keep reallocating memory for each character
                if(stringLiteral == NULL){ 
                    perror("malloc");
                    return EXIT_FAILURE;
                }
                stringLiteral[i] = c; //assing the read character to the char array
                i++; 
            }
            else { //'\n' was reached
                stringLiteral[i] = '\0'; //terminate string
                //insertString(stringLiteral); //your insertion function
                printf("%s\n", stringLiteral); //test print
                i = 0;
            }
        }
        //insertString(stringLiteral); //last read line
        printf("%s\n", stringLiteral); // test print
        
        fclose(pfile);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The problem here is that memory allocation is an expensive process and can slow down your program.

You have to weigh what's more important, the space or the speed. Unless the strings are so huge that they cannot fit in the stack, in that case memory allocation is the way to go, though it can be more sensible to allocate blocks of bytes instead of byte by byte.